# C# JSON.net populate DataGridView

Tags: c#, json, datagridview, json.net

I want to populate a datagridview (dgvNachrichten).

It has two columns ("Datum" and "Nachrichten").

This is my code:

```
try
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFile(Config.URL_MAIN, @Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + "\\" + "temp.json");
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP") + "\\" + "temp.json");
    string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var response = line;

    var des = (MyClass)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response, typeof(MyClass));
    dgvNachrichten.DataSource = des;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
{ "nachrichten": [ { "Nachricht": "text", "Datum": "datum" }, { "Nachricht": "text", "Datum": "datum" }, { "Nachricht": "text", "Datum": "datum" }, { "Nachricht": "text", "Datum": "datum" } ] }
```

And here are my Classes:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<Nachrichten_Felder> data { get; set; }
}
public class Nachrichten_Felder
{
    public string Datum { get; set; }
    public string Nachricht { get; set; }
}
```

The download works fine, and after a few seconds the form with the GridView appears, but without content...
The pieces with "Datum" in my JSON have to appear in the "Datum" Column (for every Datum a new row) and the same for "Nachrichten".

Maybe someone could help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must map `data` property to value in json file:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("nachrichten")]
    public List<Nachrichten_Felder> data { get; set; }
}
```

Also bind `DataGridView` to collection:

```
dgvNachrichten.DataSource = des.data;
```

---

Don't forget dispose `WebClient` and `StreamReader`.

Comment: Perfectly. Thank you very much!